# Does the jmeter wait for the response of previous call to initiate next call

Tags: performance, rest, http, jmeter

I am running jmeter in single thread mode and executing 1000 POST HTTP requests

```js
Every post Request returns a json data of say 2 Mb as response 
Does the jmeter wait for entire json data to come and then start next post request or just waits for the first byte of the response and then initiates the second post request.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter waits for the **full** response of previous [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) prior to starting the next one.

- `Time to first byte` = is [`Connect Time`](https://varvy.com/performance/tcp-connection-time.html) + [`Latency`](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0)
- `Time to last byte` = `Elapsed time`

See [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) to learn more about JMeter Metrics